# Setting JMS message fields in WL.Server.writeJMSMessage

Tags: jms, ibm-mobilefirst

I have WL 5.0.5.1 installed on Websphere Liberty Profile 8.5 next beta, with JMS adapter working properly. I can send text message with custom properties. I cannot change other  attributes like priority. Documentation is very cryptic and decompilation is last resort for me. I would appreciate example how to change correlation ID, priority and other message fields.

```
WL.Server.writeJMSMessage({
  destination: "myQueue",
  properties: {
    MY_PROPERTY: "123",  // becomes custom property
    priority: 9,         // becomes custom property JMSPriority is unchanged
    JMSPriority: 9,      // ignored, neither changes JMSPriority nor becomes custom property
  },
  priority: 9,    // ignored as docs do not allow params here
  JMSPriority: 9, // ignored
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the code of the JMS Adapter it looks like this is a bug, regardless to what you provide the message will be sent with default priority (4).

Currently, I don't see a workaround for setting priority.

I opened a defect internally and it will probably be fixed soon as its relatively easy to fix, thank you for helping us find this bug.

Regarding correlation, settings `JMSCorrelationID` should work.

Comment: I used "JMSCorrelationId" and "correlationId" properties, former was swallowed (ignored, did not appear on custom properties) the latter appeared as custom property; delivered message has "null" as correlation ID. The same with header field "JMSExpiration" and custom "expiration" field (set to "new Date().getTime()"); first one is ignored, the second one creates custom property. Conclusion is that **header fields do not work at all**. Is QA team on vacation? :P